# Looping through a loop each result gives multiple incorrect results

Tags: php, sql, loops

I have been scratching my head for a very long time about this PHP code. I am trying to achieve something like

->Get each status 
->Get each user in user's friends list 
->Display status' from each user that is in the user's friends list

and repeat until there is no more. I have been looking for a solution for more a few days and it is really bugging me. Here is the code I tried:

EDIT: posted schema as requested
https://kjf-tech.net/files/schema.png

```
<?php
$connect = new MySQLi($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);
$querya = "SELECT * FROM statuses ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $querya);
$ALLDATA = array();

$DBcon2 = new MySQLi($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);
if ($DBcon2->connect_errno) {
    die("ERROR : -> ".$DBcon2->connect_error);
}


while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($ALLDATA, $record);
        $queryb = "SELECT * FROM friendslist WHERE idOfPerson1='".$record['idOfUser']."' OR idOfPerson2='".$record['idOfUser']."' OR idOfPerson2='".$userRow['user_id']."' OR idOfPerson1='".$userRow['user_id']."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $queryb);
        $ALLDATA2 = array();

    while ($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($ALLDATA2, $record2);

            if($record['idOfUser'] == $userRow['user_id']) {
            echo '<div>You Posted on '.$record['whenPosted'].'<br />'.$record['content'].'</div>';
            }
            elseif($record2['idOfPerson1'] == $userRow['user_id']) {
            $query2 = $DBcon2->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id='".$record2['idOfPerson2']."'");
            $userRow2=$query2->fetch_array();
            echo '<div>'.$userRow2['username'].' Posted on '.$record['whenPosted'].'<br />'.$record['content'].'</div>';
            }
            elseif($record2['idOfPerson2'] == $userRow['user_id']) {
            $query2 = $DBcon2->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id='".$record2['idOfPerson1']."'");
            $userRow2=$query2->fetch_array();
            echo '<div>'.$userRow2['username'].' Posted on '.$record['whenPosted'].'<br />'.$record['content'].'</div>';
            }
        }
mysqli_free_result($result2);
}


$DBcon2->close();
mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is put some more thought into your database schema. It doesn't look normalized. If your schema is well thought out, the implementation is much easier. Could you post a minimal schema showing relations between tables

Comment: ok, I updated my post. I don't know if its minimal however :C

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'll work on a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema looks good, but let's take another look at the relations.  I'm going to rename some of the columns for convenience.

```
   Users:
+- user_id
|  user_name
|
|
|  Friendships:
|  fid
+- user_id
|  friend_id --------+
|  friendship_start  |
|                    |
|                    |
|  Statuses:         |
|  sid               |
+- user_id ----------+
   post_date
   content
```

If you just wanted to find statuses of your friends, the query would look thus:

```
SELECT statuses.content 
FROM friendships, statuses 
WHERE friendship.user_id=? AND 
    friendships.friend_id = statuses.user_id
```

You would, of course, `bind` the appropriate `user_id` value when you `->prepare()` the statement.

> (See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for the proper way to do sql.  You **don't ever** want to do something like mysql_query("select * from table where id=".$_POST['id']) because it's open to SQL injection)

Unfortunately, though, this does not include your own status in the query results.  We'll have to do a little more work on the query...

```
SELECT statuses.content
FROM friendships, statuses
WHERE
  ( friends.user_id = ? AND
    friends.friend_id = stuatuses.user_id ) 
  OR
  statuses.user_id = ?
ORDER BY statuses.post_date DESC
```

So far, so good... but we don't have the names nor the post date.  The post date is easy, just add that to the select:
`SELECT statuses.content, statuses.post_date`

To add the name, we have to get data from Users also.

```
SELECT users.user_name, statuses.content, statuses.post_date
FROM users, friendships, statuses
WHERE 
  users.user_id = ? AND
  (
    ( users.user_id = friendships.user_id AND 
      friendships.friend_id = statuses.user_id )
    OR
    statuses.user_id = users.user_id
  )
ORDER BY statuses.post_date DESC
```

And there you have it; the database does all the work for you.  No need for nested queries and such.  This will just give you the simple list to print on your page.  Please keep in mind that this is off the top of my head, so you may have to tweak it if I overlooked something.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! I had to fiddle around with the SQL and PHP code to sort out some issues. It had first duplicated the user's post but however I fixed that. Thank you again :D

Comment: Excellent :)  Glad to have helped.